# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 6-26-2015

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I tried several Q&A in here and made this piece of code:
The idea is to compare dt1 with dt2 and do something later.

```
date = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt1 = dt1.AddDays(-4);
String dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

On the last line I am having this exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

While debugging this are the values:
`date = 06/05/2015`
`dt1 = "01-Jun-15 12:00:00 AM`
`datestr = 6-26-2015`

Comment: On the last line I am having this exception: {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}  
    

While debugging this are the values:
date = "06/05/2015"  
dt1 = "01-Jun-15 12:00:00 AM"  
datestr = "6-26-2015"

Comment: Should edit your question to add that info. :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a reason why you convert a `DateTime` to `string` only to parse it right back to a `DateTime` again? Wouldn't `DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.Date;` (or `DateTime.Today`) have the same result in a cleaner way?

Comment: Hi Corak, I am trying to handle different geographies date format that's why,tough I am not sure is the right way.

Comment: @dracebus - Okay, to avoid headache when working with `DateTime` (or any datatype with a culture specific representation), I usually convert it to the real datatype it's supposed to be as soon as possible, *only* work with that and only get the culture specific representation again when displaying the data as late as possible. -- also try to keep the `IFormatProvider` in sync. Currently, you don't specify one in the `ToString()` which will default to `CurrentCulture`. And in your case `CurrentCulture != InvariantCulture`. Which also causes a part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format is incorrect if `datestr` value is "6-26-2015"
you should use this:

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "M-d-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`ParseExact` tries to match the input string with the given format.

In your case input string is `6-26-2015` and format is `M/d/yyyy`, `-` and `/` can not be matched so the exception is thrown.